# get_terms_args ordering by meta key not working

Tags: terms, meta-query, term-meta

I have a custom taxonomy called "edition". Each edition has a meta key "_edition" that stores an incremental number from 1 to N. So, if I have an edition called "Edition 13", it will store "_edition" meta key with value of 13.

My question is: I'm trying to order my terms in admin with this "_edition" meta key. To achieve that, I'm trying to use the "get_terms_args" filter, this way:

```php
add_filter("get_terms_args", "MyTheme_GetTermsArgs", 10, 2);

function MyTheme_GetTermsArgs($args, $taxonomies)
{
    if(is_admin() && in_array("edition", $taxonomies)){
        $args['orderby'] = "meta_value_num";
        $args['meta_key'] = "_edition";
        $args['order'] = "DESC";
    }
    
    return $args;
}
```

But the resulting order is very strange. There are around 123 editions, and the result ordering is

1, 2, 3, [...], 8, 9, 10, 100, 101, 102, 103, [...], 109, 11, 110, 111, 112, 113, [...], 118, 119, 12, 120, 121, 122, 123, 13, 14, 15, 16 [...].

The expected is a "normal" ordering from 1 to 123. I've already tried changing "orderby" to "meta_value", specifying an "meta_type". All without success.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are seeing there is alphabetical ordering. Are you sure no other filters are running on get_terms_args?

Comment: @vancoder I've searched my whole project for anything else calling the get_terms_args filter, and doesn't found anything. Also, I've tested setting the add_filter priority to PHP_INT_MAX, to make sure it's the last thing done in this filter, and stills not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tests... Finally I've found a solution.

Instead using get_terms_args filter, I've changed to parse_term_query action. My resulting code looks this way now:

```php
add_action("parse_term_query", "MyTheme_ParseTermQuery", PHP_INT_MAX, 1);

function MyTheme_ParseTermQuery(&$query)
{
    $taxonomy = $query->query_vars['taxonomy'][0];
    if($taxonomy == "edition"){
        $query->query_vars['order'] = "ASC";
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = "meta_value_num";
        $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = [[
            'key' => "_edition",
            'type' => "NUMERIC"
        ]];
    }
}
```

Now it's ordering as expected.

Comment: You saved my life man. Thank you, I have been pulling my hair out.